# star rating for workers in a flutter app using NODE JS with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, flutter, phpmyadmin

anyone can help me in my flutter project. I designed a page that shows star rating for a worker, from one to five and I want to write a suitable function in node js file with MYSQL database in phpMyAdmin, the query of the function aims to take the input rate from the user and send it to the database according to the id or username of the worker and calculate the average rating from multiple users for the same worker

Comment: please include some code and error related your problem if any

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hVkB3BUP

Comment: that's my flutter code but i couldn't start writing the suitable query in my node js file